# Who is this multiple "unknown (google)" user on SU?

Tags: discussion

There are a few of them, example: Click on the 'Users' tab and sort by name, they show as "unknown (Google), however they don't show up when you filter the user results.

Some of them even [post replies](https://superuser.com/questions/20972/what-else-do-linux-distros-need-in-order-attract-the-non-geek-user-groups/21564#21564), which read very human and sane.

Are these just normal users going through a Google service? Also I did try look for this answer before posting. Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: *> Some of them even post replies, which read very human and sane.* Only *some* of them sound sane? `;-D`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A name of "unknown" indicates that they have signed in using an OpenId, but have not filled out their profile - the bit in brackets (Google, in this case) is the OpenId provider where they don't provide a nickname.

Comment: Some providers will send back a nick or profile name to auto-populate the DisplayName on SO. Some providers, like Google and Yahoo, don't.

Comment: updated to paraphrase (thanks I learn something new!)

Answer (score 2):

When I first signed into meta (using my gmail openID), it listed my name as "unknown (google)" until I changed it in my profile.  It is other people signing in using an openID, then never editing their profile.